# S3 File upload policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a site which allows users to define their subdomains
xxx.mysite.com

I allow the users to upload their own avatars and logos - ideally, it should upload directly to s3.

1

I am able to generate the policy http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html here.

However, I do not know what to give 
["starts-with", "$success_action_redirect", "http://xxx.mysite.com/"]

I can leave it out but I am not very comfortable allowing anyone to just upload easily. How can I add more restrictions?

I currently restrict the content-type to images

2 https and http

I know that I can force ssl on the entire site and use https://xxx.mysite.com for success_action_redirect.

Is there a regex I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

It is not possible to do a wildcard search. We can do only starts-with.

I just restricted it to https for now. The other way to do it is to have a common code for upload across subdomains and use a parent.xx browser functions. Since it is in the same domain, browser will not complain and the s3 policy will go through.